# Is there any way to measure sound intensity in decibels without using a microphone?

Tags: frequency, esp32, microphone, sound, decibel

I am trying to measure sound intensity in decibels without using microphone in a home automation project. Due to privacy concerns, I don't want to use a microphone in the device. Is there any way I can measure sound intensity without a microphone using an ESP32 microcontroller with some precision?

Comment: `Intensity` is proportional to the peak pressure change rate, squared. Microphones are designed to be very sensitive devices for pressure changes. Would it be acceptable for your use to `impair` a microphone so that it responds to sound pressure, but very slowly so useless for audio purposes? Or would that still qualify as a microphone and be forbidden? If so, you are looking for a different kind of sensor and may need to spend time studying the topic to better frame the question. (I doubt the tiny amounts of dissipated energy per unit time would produce measurable sensor heating.)

Comment: If you’re in control of the microphone then you’re in control of the privacy - or will this device be handed off to people who don’t trust you?

Comment: Problem is that this is IOT based device to be used in homes and in offices.  to attain wider costumer market i was thinking to not use microphone so it can be installed anywhere without any concern.

Comment: What about only registering the signal above a threshold?

Comment: thank you very much for input @Neil_UK that seen to the solution for my problem but i am not sure about overlap with the frequency spectrum. i just want to measure audible sound intensity in specific areas around house.

Comment: this seems tobe a marketing problem. Use a microphone and call it a sound level sensor,

Comment: Use the microphone to detect sound, and an analog level detector.  That's an op-amp as a precision diode followed by a low pass filter.  That gives you a slowly changing DC signal that represents the sound pressure level.  You connect that to the ADC. Call the microphone and the analog components a "sound level sensor."  The ADC only gets the rectified and filtered signal - it cannot "spy on" anyone.

Comment: A loudspeaker can be used as a microphone if that's of any use?

Comment: Related: I read an engineering paper on devices used to determine if a vehicle is parked in a specific area.  Cameras were not allowed for privacy reasons.  The solution was to send out a signal with a tiny transmitter and check for the duration of the return of that signal (similar to how radar works).  Perhaps a similar technology can be used here?

Comment: The summary of all the contributions so far is that you don't have a technical problem - you can sense the power of the audio without being able to read intelligible speech, either in analogue or digital domains. However, you have a trust issue, how do you sell to your market on how you've achieved that? It's a tricky sell to position, as Dave Tweed points out, they have to be paranoid enough to care, and so pay a premium for your product, but not so paranoid that you fail to convince.

Comment: A simple solution that works in all environments <100 dB is to add a 120 dB siren to the "sensor" and always report 120 dB without even listening. /j

Comment: What **specifically** are the privacy concerns? Whose concerns are they and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to improve the definition of your problem.

## Privacy

Does that mean any talking is unintelligible? The fact that some sounds can be heard, at a specific time, even if they are unintelligible as speech, would still leak a lot of private information in some scenarios. What level of privacy do you want?

## Sound Intensity

Is this to control a sound source over which you have control - ie known spectrum and time of occurrence? Or is it to detect some known, or unknown, background noise, in what parts of the audio spectrum? What sort of sound do you want to measure the intensity of? An audio bandwidth, and possibly a weighting specification, is the minimum that's required here. If you can tolerate responding to a 10 second average for instance, that allows you to really trash speech intelligibility without harming noise detection.

## Provably private?

There are things you can do to render speech unintelligible while preserving noise power in some parts of the spectrum like low pass filtering, or even all of the spectrum by randomly shuffling samples. However, if that's in closed-source code, how would your customers be assured that you're not secretly recording them anyway? Even with open source, if it's a reprogammable device, how could they be sure that some other third party has not defeated the audio scrambling? How paranoid is your intended market?

Comment: NB that you can be as honest as you want, some tinfoil hat conspiracy theories will emerge. People are incredibly bad at assessing who it what is really damaging their privacy.

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. - "Hey Siri, what things in my home could be damaging my privacy?" ;)

Comment: This. If customers realize that a device is reacting to sound in any way, some will assume that it is capable of recording or transmitting the sound, regardless of whether a "microphone" visibly exists in the product. Similar product: automatic flush urinals and toilets -- how do you know they're not taking pictures?

Comment: Randomly-shuffling samples is basically just a noisy low-pass filter. It doesn't scramble all of the spectrum. Doing a Fourier transform, scrambling _that_, then inverting the Fourier transform would work for that.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 the random shuffling suggestion is rather moot, considering the far better alternative of Constantine's power preserving audio destroying analogue solution.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 as you can see by the fact that the Fourier transform is perfectly invertible: your proposed method has absolutely no advantage over a time-domain scrambler in terms of removing information. A time domain scrambler, of course, if properly designed, does affect all the bandwidth equally.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Consider the following shuffling - take 2 seconds of audio samples, and sort them by value - I wonder how intelligible that would be? I doubt Audacity has that filter, but it might be a nice exercise to write.

Answer (score 23):

If your customers aren't electrical engineers, how would they tell a small microphone on your main circuit board from say an oscillator, opamp, or voltage regulator? So any customer that only buys your device because you claim that there's no microphone on it will have to trust you anyways. Or they need to be able to tear down your device and verify it themselves, and put it back together, then used the exact verified device. Not realistic.

But you can't sell a device without a microphone anyways:

Any device that can measure the instantaneous sound pressure *is* the definition of a microphone. While you only need the power of the sound, you might find [more exotic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/695915/359402) ways of measuring that, but realistically, you could reasonably reconstruct the amplitude even from that power. So, functionally, anything that is fast enough at measuring acoustic power is equivalent to a microphone.

So, you'll use a microphone to do what by all practical means makes a microphone.

But you can electronically and verifiably make its output useless for understanding speech. It's not what you'd do in a mass product, because it's more expensive and less precise than doing it in software, but one can look at the circuit board and go: yes, if I was an electrical engineer, I could see that this output contains no reconstructible audio.

Idea is simple:

1. Make isolated board, to prove that only a single supply voltage, ground, and an output signal connect the board to the rest of the system
2. Use a crappy electret microphone as sound converter on that board,
3. Use an opamp as preamplifier stage (single-ended, i.e. virtual ground somewhere around half supply voltage), (1. Opamp) *to make the signal usable in your correct"
4. Use a simple RC low pass to limit bandwidth to audible ranges, *to only measure frequencies you care about*
5. Feed preamplified, filtered signal into simple precision recertifier opamp circuit (2. Opamp) *to convert to signal that is proportional to the square root of power*
6. Follow that by simple envelope detector circuit (diode, resistors, capacitor) *to get an exponentially decaying quasi-power signal with little reconstructability of original audio*,
7. Follow that by simple logarithmic amplifier opamp circuit, (3. Opamp) *to convert to logarithmic units, i.e. make decibel to some arbitrary power standard*
8. Use an active filter (4. Opamp) to limit the bandwidth of the logarithmic power signal to, say 0.25 Hz (or whatever update rate on the "averaged decibel sound pressure" you need) *to erase remaining possibility to reconstruct audio*
9. Feed the resulting signal to output connector

Add well-labeled test points throughout the circuit, and add a link to the schematic to your board's silkscreen, so that anyone can verify what you're doing there. Lay out the circuit spaciously to make clear you're not counting on crosstalk as backdoor channel.

It's very common to get four opamps in a single IC package, and every sensible design would use that, but you might opt to use individual opamps, just to be able to lay out your signal processing steps in a straight line and demonstrate the principle.

Will that help anyone really trust your device?

Yeah, not many people; there's not going to be many electrical engineers able to read that schematic, and even if they did, the rest of your system isn't any more trustworthy.

Any capacitor connected to a pin on a microcontroller that can be configured as analog input could be abused as microphone, if you're determined enough. So you're catering to a slightly paranoid, but not *very* paranoid target audience that happens to be electronics experts. You've got a product trust, not a technical problem, so tell marketing your product is going to be more expensive and that they need to sell that as a feature.

Comment: I like the idea of trashing the audio with simple analogue processing

Comment: If I saw such an elaborate setup, I would be suspicious that there was another microphone hidden somewhere else in the system.

Comment: @DaveTweed see, you're smart enough to fall out of the target audience "slightly paranoid, technical, but not paranoid enough"

Comment: @Neil_UK note that the idea was born from the fact that one can somewhat trace, especially with enough testpoints, what happens in these analog stages. And they are quite minimally thrashing, to be honest: you need the rectification for conversion to power, no matter how you measure that. The low-passing is necessary to get rid of the higher-frequency self-intermodulation products you get with that. The logarithm needs to be done prior to the final "average", because avg(dB(sqrt(power))) ≠ dB(avg(sqrt(power))), and you definitely need the final average, as the audio is almost completely ...

Comment: ... reconstructible up to that point.

Comment: +1 on envelope detector. That’s is how I would do it.

Comment: nitpick: a microphone is not the definition of something that measures sound power. it also measures phase. The OP requires only power, so physically you can solve it by an object that is too slow to capture phase but absorbs the energy. think of a photodiode or bolometer

Comment: @tobalt fair, especially considering https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/695915/359402. Let me fix that.

Comment: Reading it a second time, I said "instantaneous pressure", and that's really that amplitude of what a microphone measures (or the derivative of it), and phase is just a property of a tone that can be deduced from the history of the instantaneous pressure!

Comment: @tobalt fixed the wording, thanks for nitpicking, actually!

Answer (score 9):

Any device or transducer that can convert sound to electrical signal is by definition a microphone.

Even capacitors can exhibit microphonics and can ruin your signal by converting audio or mechanical vibrations into electrical signal and summing it with your original signal.

So no, you can't sense audio intensity without something that can be called a microphone.

You could try to use speakers or piezoelectric discs as microphones and just not call it a microphone.

But if you want to accurately measure sound pressure levels, nothing will beat a good microphone. Or even a cheap average electret mic capsule.

Comment: Your main assumption is wrong: a microphone is not the definition of something that measures sound power. it also measures phase. The OP requires only power, so physically you can solve it by an object that is too slow to capture phase but absorbs the energy. think of a photodiode or bolometer

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in fact, it is a common ultrasound measuring technique to measure sound intensity by looking at the force exerted on a target (with a sensitive weighing apparatus).

[Ultrasonic power output measurement](https://www.nist.gov/publications/ultrasonic-power-output-measurement-pulsed-radiation-pressure)

It's not quite so sensitive as a microphone, and the amount of
momentum in a sound wave is small, but it isn't impossible.   Because
the target is heavy, and only the net pressure is noted, there's no
way to pick up details like speech.   It only detects one direction of
sound  motion, the P (longitudinal compression) wave.

Comment: Oh neat! Wasn't aware of that!

Comment: Honestly, I think **this** is the answer. It's the only solution that does not measure phase and thus cannot fundamentally restore the sound information.

Answer (score 1):

**Connect only the control interface of a smart microphone**

Some MEMS microphones include a wakeup circuit that monitors sound level. This is often accessed by I2C, while the audio data is available through a separate I2S connection. You could connect the I2C and leave the I2S unconnected, thus making it impossible to read actual audio to the main processor.

For example [VM3011](https://www.mouser.fi/datasheet/2/960/Vesper_Technologies_VM3011_Datasheet_5b5_5d-1893207.pdf) provides `WOS_PGA_GAIN` register that reads ambient sound level with 1.5 dB resolution and 0.5 second averaging period.

Unfortunately the availability of Vesper products seems rather poor currently. Knowles has some similar ones like [IA611](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/4568/IA611_v1.2.pdf), but those have a whole CPU on the microphone.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: if it's louder than 200 decibels, you're dead.

Anything less than that becomes an exercise in measuring transducer displacement at increasing frequencies from infrasound to ultrasound.

Somewhere in there the devices popularly known as microphones are relevant.

---

Noting what others have said and considering current privacy considerations, I would suggest that the issue is not so much what sort of transducer is used but what is retained in recognisable form or sent to an external server.

Comment: It will be hard to achieve 200dB SPL. That would mean a sound pressure level between vacuum and twice the atmospheric pressure, or 2 Atm. 1 Atm would be 194 dB. The eruption of Krakatoa reportedly was 180dB, measured at distance of 100km.

Comment: @Justme I was waiting for that :-) An excessively-smart colleague asked me the same thing 20 years ago, which prompted me to ask a past-life academic who had been involved in... various stuff related to non-linear acoustics... hence "210 [dB] N.A.S.A. 400,000 ACOUSTIC WATTS EXPERIMENTAL NOISEMAKER 48 FEET ACROSS OF CONCRETE AND STEEL". There's a lot of other stuff in the table he sent me which you probably don't want if you value your supper. Happy New Year!.